# kustomize helm in argoCD

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, argocd, kustomize

I'm trying to activate kustomize for argoCD. But here's the error I get.

```
The Kubernetes API could not find kustomize.config.k8s.io/Kustomization for requested resource argo/. Make sure the "Kustomization" CRD is installed on the destination cluster.
```

Can anyone help me please.

I used this documentation to configure my argoCD config.
https://dev.to/camptocamp-ops/use-kustomize-to-post-render-helm-charts-in-argocd-2ml6

Answer (score 2):

You likely included a `kustomization.yml` file in your application. kustomization.yml files should ONLY be used to generate manifests.

Comment: Make sure the `spec.source.directory` field is not set for your Application. That field will force Argo CD to interpret the files as raw Kubernetes manifests instead of Kustomize sources.

Answer (score 0):

If you decompose the error log:

> The Kubernetes API could not find kustomize.config.k8s.io/Kustomization for requested resource argo/.

Means that your command tries to find a `kustomize.config.k8s.io/Kustomization` CRD in the cluster but it's not there. A CRD (Custom Resource Definition) is a custom definition, where `Service` or `ConfigMap` are preexisting definitions.

Check more doc on this here:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/

> Make sure the "Kustomization" CRD is installed on the destination cluster.

Means that you should try to find a way to install the `kustomize.config.k8s.io/Kustomization` in your cluster.
Checking with chatGPT with "How to install CRD kustomize.config.k8s.io/Kustomization in a cluster ?" seems to give a pretty good answer.

Comment: you shouldnt be installing Kustomize on a cluster; its a manifest generation tool

Comment: That's exactly how to not use chatGPT. Kustomize is not a CRD and shall not be installed within a cluster. It's a tool used to generate kubernetes manifest using base and overlay approach.

Comment: Ok perhaps I should delete my answer then, but why does the log speaks about crd ?

Comment: op is trying to install a `kind: Kustomization` object. The cluster doesn't know about it because no resources of its name exist in the cluster, therefore the cluster says "please install this resources before usage". However this `kind: Kustomization` shoudn't be instaled in the cluster - it's a mistake from OP. Read more about CRD here : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/